# Problem unlocking Mac using Touch ID

Tags: macos, user-account, login-screen, touch-id

I got a problem with using the Touch ID to unlock my MacBook Pro 15" running macOS High Sierra. Whenever I lock my screen by clicking the <kbd></kbd> → Lock Screen (or <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>), Mac locks me out and shows me a password window.

[image: You must enter a password to unlock the screen.]

I cannot use Touch ID to unlock it, I have to click the Switch User button, then go to the normal Login screen, and then I can use Touch ID to unlock it.

[image: Touch ID or Enter Password]

But my colleague, sees the normal Login screen always when he locks the screen on his MacBook.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix my issue regarding the Lock Screen.

I have [OpenSC](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC) and [mPollux](https://eevertti.vrk.fi/en/mac-os-x) Digisign clients installed on my MacBook Pro.

OpenSC was installed for logging into macOS with Smart Card and mPollux was installed for ID authentication.

I uninstalled both of them. Now when I lock the screen, I have the normal Lock Screen back, and can use Touch ID to unlock it. But I don't know which application affected it.

[image]